# CategoryId in venues search not working correctly

Tags: api, search, categories, foursquare

In foursquare Api documentation for "Search venues" https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search it states

```
"categoryId  - A comma separated list of categories to limit results to. This is an experimental feature and subject to change or may be unavailable. If you specify categoryId you may also specify a radius. If specifying a top-level category, all sub-categories will also match the query."
```

Realise its supposed to be experimental, but when I provide Food category i.e. `4d4b7105d754a06374d81259`, it only returns a few local results, the rest are miles away. 
However if I execute same search on website sing Food category, it returns correctly lots of results, assuming its the last bit `"If specifying a top-level category, all sub-categories will also match the query"` is not working , i.e. its not searching sub-categories ?

Any fix work around for this ?

Thanks,

Neil Pepper

Comment: Can you post example API requests you're making, with client_secret / oauth tokens removed?

Comment: Sure, using foursquare test its https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fll%3D51.140797,0.274064%26categoryId%3D+4d4b7105d754a06374d81259

So important bit is venues/search?ll=51.140797,0.274064&categoryId= 4d4b7105d754a06374d81259

However when logged in to foursquare and use https://foursquare.com/explore?q=Food at same location i get many more local locations.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a [/venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) request with its default intent of intent=checkin. This returns a filter on nearby results, heavily biased by distance since it's trying to guess where the user might be checking in.

Foursquare Explore uses the [/venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) endpoint and attempts to return recommended results for a query. If you want to get the sorts of results you get in that tool, call /venues/explore?section=food

Comment: This question is so old and categoryid filter still not working. I found this a better way, use explore and a section. Thank you.